# Python makefile with multiple arguments

Tags: python, makefile

I am trying to write a makefile to build my .py files to an executable. The current makefile I have is:

```
DIR=$(PWD)
STA=start.py
FILES = utility.py \
        start.py
all:$(FILES)
    echo "$(PY) $(DIR)/$(STA)" '"$1"' > test
    chmod 777 test
clean:
    rm *.pyc test
```

But it only takes one argument. If I write `echo "$(PY) $(DIR)/$(STA)" '"$1"' '"$2"' > test` then it takes two arguments. 
But the number of arguments I am supposed to take is not fixed.
Is there any idea I can take multiple arguments?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if understand but how about

```
echo "$(PY) $(DIR)/$(STA)" $(PARAMS) > test
```

Then you could

```
make all PARAMS="foo bar baz"
```

Comment: The problem is that # of arguments is not deterministic...  I don't know how many arguments may be used...